# import var firebaseui = require('firebaseui'); error window is not defined

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebaseui

i have error window is not defined when import firebaseui in my project

var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');

\node_modules\firebaseui\dist\npm.js:30
componentHandler["register"]=componentHandler.register;componentHandler["downgradeElements"]=componentHandler.downgradeElements;window.componentHandler=componentHandler;window["componentHandler"]=componentHandler;

Comment: why are you trying to include a ui component in node?

Comment: window is a glass object, typically found on a vehicle or building, which provides visibility to the outside. Window is now defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firebaseui provides UI components for web applications running in a browser.  It doesn't support node.js.

Comment: so.. how to use it with express?